# Scrape web with login session (using python scrapy)

Tags: python, authentication, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to extra some data under a login session using y. Usually when I intercept data I can view the format data in the network tab. In this login page, when the log on is submitted, I can't seems to find the format data tab.

https://lumen.ni.com/nicif/login.xhtml

Can anyone advice ?

My current implementation:

```
import y
from y import FormReuest

class LoginSpider(y.Spider):
name = 'example.com'


def start_requests(self):
    return [y.FormRequest("https://lumen.ni.com/nicif/login.xhtml",
                               formdata={'LoginForm:email': 'email', 'LoginForm:password': 'password'},
                               callback=self.logged_in)]

def logged_in(self, response):
    if("Please use correct email & password combination") in str(response.body):
        print("fail")
    else:
        data = {'p_part_number':'779494-01','p_duration':'','p_duration_uom':''}
        yield FormRequest(url="http://sine.ni.com/apps/utf8/nipp.purchase_form_ajax", formdata=data)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of other parameters they are using along with form, they are `hidden` in the login form, you need to send them too along with your request.

[image]

Comment: wow, thanks. I didn't noticed that there is a login.xhtml, I always checked xhr tab so didn't realize that's there. May I ask how to I get the information of the javax.faces.ViewStates to send along with form ?

Comment: As I said its in the login page, look for hidden input fields

Comment: Is it possible to do scraping past a /login while the /login is disallowed in the robots.txt?

Comment: @Mushirih yes its possible, set `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False` in settings.py

Comment: @Umair I have only one file which has all my code, tell me how to implement this flag